# php soap server own prefix element

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm programming my soap server with php, the server runs with the "standard" code:

```
$options = array('uri' => 'http://myserver/wsdl', 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 );
$server = new SoapServer("http://myserver/wsdl/wsas.wsdl", $options );
$server -> setClass("myclass"); 
$server->handle();
```

And the systems work perfect with the common wsdl structure:

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://myserver/wsdl.php">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:element1>
         <subelement1>
            <subId1>?</subId1>
            <subName1>?</subName1>
         </subelement1>
         <subpart>
            <subIdp>?</subId1>
            <subNamePart>?</subName1>
         </subpart>
    ...
```

The wsas.wsdl structure:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsas="http://myserver/wsdl.php" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="wsas" targetNamespace="http://myserver/wsdl.php">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://myserver/wsdl.php">
      <xsd:element name="element">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="subelement1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="subId1" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xsd:element name="subName1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="subpart" minOccurs="0" maxoccurs="unbounded">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="subIdp" type="xsd:int"/>
                  <xsd:element name="subNamePart" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
...
```

The structure sent by client is different, that should be necessarily **wsas:element** instead of **element1**. 
I searched here, google for it, but cann't find the answer. I tried changing the name, changing definitions, nothing works .

How can i get the tag "wsas:element" working?

Thanks

Comment: how does your wsas.wsdl look like?

Comment: I edited and added the schema part.